# certificates not grouped under trusted certificates in azure

Tags: azure, ssl

This question will be easy for those who work in cloud services or for those who having some good knowledge about windows azure.

I have a ssl certificate specified its thumbprint and other details in configuration file. When my package is deployed in the cloud service, the certificate doesn't get grouped under trusted certificate group.Insted it gets grouped under intermediate certificate group in all the instances. Because of this I am getting some certificate issue while accessing a site.

On googling I could find from the microsoft blog, that all the certificates from trusted sources will be grouped under trusted certificates in the azure cloud service virtual machines. But here it is not doing so..

Any ideas on this?

Any comments would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an os upgrade from Microsoft. It was fixed by them and now this seems to be working perfect..

For more: visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee924680.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When deploying certificates to an Azure cloud instance, you may have to include more than jus the SSL certificate to secure the domain. You may also have to list any intermediate certificates, as well as the root certificate. Have a look at this article that describes how to confiugre chained certificates for Azure and let me know if it helps at all.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuredevsupport/archive/2010/02/24/how-to-install-a-chained-ssl-certificate.aspx

Comment: I already have those(root and intermediate) certificates in the cloud service.But the issue is that the root certs are not grouped under Trusted Certificate group.Instead it automatically gets grouped under Intermediate Certificates group.